# Maximum Packets per second .NET sockets

Tags: .net, sockets, packet, rate

I realize that the performance would be related to the machine. But given say two core i7 PCs with a gigabit LAN between them, with one sending out 1k packets as fast as it can and one receiving them, what would be a rough guess of how many packets per second you would expect?

I ask because I am implementing a protocol using raw sockets and I can send out around 100,000 1k packets a second but I only seems to be able to receive somewhere between 20,000 and 40,000pps. The sending is remarkably constant but the receive packets per second varies wildly between the two values. 
When I hit this receive limit the CPU util is around 20%. Why is the send , apparently, so much faster than the receive?

I am not doing any processing on the receive but simply calling receive again after the last receive with the same buffer. I am using BeginSendTo and BeginReceiveFrom with corresponding EndReceive etc. 
Maybe 20 -40,000 pps is very good? 
What sort of pps do other people achieve and do you start missing any packets at higher packet rates? 
If you are looking to "wring every last ounce" out of sockets tx/rx what are the best methods to use and things to look out for.

All pointers / ideas to try welcome.

Comment: Do you need to use TCP/IP, or can you use UDP (does order and guarantee of delivery matter)?  What are you sending in each packet (makeup of the packet)? How many hops are between the two machines?

Comment: If you're sending same data to multiple places, combining udp with multicasting will be of great help (if your network equipment supports it of course).

Comment: Thankyou for your comments. It is SCTP which sits atop IP. Ie is not UDP or TCP. Hence need for RAW sockets. Packet data size can be as small as common header (12 bytes) plus small chunk (4) bytes. or as large as MTU. LAN architecture is Gigabit LAN with machines on same subnet.

Comment: tested seperate thread result 75,000pps rx. I tried an IPv4 and IPv6 socket each in their own thread result 25,000pps for both. Combined Ipv4 and Ipv6 socket in single worker thread result 27,000pps.  beginrx on single Ipv4 socket result 45,000pps. Thought about winpcap but even wireshark struggles at 50,000 pps.rumour is send is slow. I wanted a way to make the SCTP are performant as possible but easy to distribute. Is around the 50,000 pps mark the best I can expect from .NET sockets? with small packet sizes the bandwidth is low ie tens of Mbs and CPU is low ~3% but I still hit this limit?

Comment: Its just seems with such low cpu and multicore machine you should be able to get more. NIC doesn't seem to be the problem as the rx pps rate varies markedly depending on which method of rx you choose. What is the limit and what imposes it?